# Best alternative for SearchView for Android api level 7 and up?

Tags: android, compatibility, searchview

I have created my app for version 4.0+ and now adding support for devices running on Android api level 7+.

I have added ActionBarSherlock for action bar and similar components; so I've solved many problems with that. However, I couldn't find a way for SearchView component. Should I create a custom view which has edit box and call it only devices which don't have SearchView?

How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you use actionBarSherlock, you can use SearchViewCompat .

you can also check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12457537/878126) that i've created.

if you wish to customize the way it looks on multiple android versions, you can use addTextChangedListener on the editText that you will probably use.

Comment: Since I was already using ActionBarSherlock, using SearchViewCompat solved my problem; but I used "setOnQueryTextListener" instead of "addTextChangedListener" on searchView object.

Comment: yes, i just wrote that you should use it only if you customize the way it looks , using your own customized view.

Answer (score 4):

See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/search/backward-compat.html#provide-sd) from Android developers site.

PS: Not as per your question, but ABS is deprecated since last Android API. Google rolled out their own implementation of comaptible action bar.

Comment: Would you please share a link related to Google's own backwards compatible actionbar which would take place of ABS?

Comment: @frankish This: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html. Basically you use it as the native `ActionBar`, you just need to know how to use `android-support-v7-appcompat`

Answer (score 0):

For that you can implement [**TextWatcher**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) in your Activity