# How to use or workaround searchManager.getSearchableInfo() on Android API 7?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I can't find anywhere how to use the support v7 appcompat library with `searchManager.getSearchableInfo()`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.search_widget);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo( searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}
```

Here's what I get:

```
Call requires API level 8 (current min is 7): android.app.SearchManager#getSearchableInfo   MainActivity.java   /MyApp/src/com/aat  line 113    Android Lint Problem
```

And if I ignore the error with @TargetApi I get this:

```
11-21 22:14:48.108: E/AndroidRuntime(2387): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.SearchManager.getSearchableInfo
```

Any help?

Comment: This was indeed added in API 8, see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#getSearchableInfo(android.content.ComponentName)

Comment: I'm not doubting Lint. I need a workaround. How do I accomplish the same thing on API lvl 7?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried actionBarShelock with SearchViewCompat for API 7?

[Best alternative for SearchView for Android api level 7 and up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206085/best-alternative-for-searchview-for-android-api-level-7-and-up)